# Converting UTC timestamp string to UNIX timestamp number - Javascript vs PHP

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp, utc

> Do NOT answer this question with the following:
>
> - "Javascript UNIX timestamps are in milliseconds, PHP UNIX timestamps are in seconds"
> - "Javascript runs in the browser, PHP runs on the server, and the clocks might not match"
>
> Any answers to that effect will be downvoted!

I'm running into an issue where on the exact same computer, Node.js and PHP yield different timestamps when converting a UTC timestamp string to an UNIX timestamp integer.

Reference code in PHP:

```php
$a = '2022-07-20T17:30:28.771';
list($b, $c) = explode('.', $a);
$d = strtotime($b) * 1000 + ((int) $c);
// $d is 1658338228771 ms
```

In Javascript:

```js
const a = '2022-07-20T17:30:28.771';
const b = new Date(a);
const d = b.valueOf();
// d is 1658352628771 ms
```

See the difference:

```
PHP:     1658338228771 milliseconds
Node.js: 1658352628771 milliseconds
```

The difference is exactly 14400000 milliseconds (4 hours).

Since I am in the EDT timezone (UTC-4:00), that probably explains the difference. My question is, how do I adjust for this?

What is the proper procedure for converting a UTC timestamp to a UNIX timestamp with millisecond precision that matches in both PHP and Javascript?

Comment: Did you try with `date_default_timezone_set("UTC");` which is a good practice by the way.

Comment: @ITgoldman agreed, and yes, that is my setting.

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation, my PHP default timezone was set to UTC, so the timestamp was interpreted as UTC.

Javascript, on the other hand, interprets it as a local timestamp.

To get reliable conversion of a UTC timestamp to a UNIX timestamp regardless of time zone settings, I need to do this:

In PHP:

```php
$a = '2022-07-20T17:30:28.771Z';
$b = new DateTime($a);
$d = (int) $b->format('Uv');
// 1658338228771
```

In Javascript:

```js
const a = '2022-07-20T17:30:28.771Z';
const b = Date.parse(a);
const d = b.valueOf();
// 1658338228771
```

In both cases, it is important that the UTC timestamp end with `Z`, so that the parsers know to treat it as UTC.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a datetime object with UTC timezone.
- Add 4 hours
- Get the timestamp.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2022-07-20T17:30:28.771', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dateTime->add(new DateInterval('PT4H'));
echo $dateTime->format('Uv');
```

prints the same as your javascript code.

```
1658352628771
```